# Incompatible Mail System setting detected

Tags: emails

In order to get the Newsletter (Simplenews module) to send out emails correctly (in HTML format) I selected HTMLMailSYstem in the mail system settings. Having the DefaultMailSystem setting instead, does not work, in a sense that it only sends out plaintext newsletters, not html.

The status report however is giving me the following error:

Printer, email and PDF versions - Send by email
Incompatible Mail System setting detected
The send by email module requires the use of the DefaultMailSystem, please configure it in the Mail System Settings page.

Is it possible to have different mail system settings for different modules? Or is there another way for me to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

[SMTP Authentication Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module works best with the Print module. I has an option allow sending mail in HTML format.

> This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send email directly to an SMTP server. The module supports SMTP authentication and can even connect to servers using SSL if supported by PHP.